# Nested CSSTransitionGroup not adding classes in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, animation

In the code below you can see that when user hits "/" path the Dashboard component is rendered. Because it's wrapped in a transition group it animates in.

I have a component inside this (`Test`) which is also wrapped in a transition group, but because it's a child of `Dashboard` it never really enters or leaves, so my `enter` and `leave` classes are not being added. How can I ensure these classes get added?

[image: code]

Comment: Try wrapping your `<Route>` in a switch tag: `<Switch location={location}> <Route exact location={} key={} path="/" component={}/></Switch>` https://codesandbox.io/s/xkRokLoyq

Comment: Thanks, is TransitionGroup stable? I've not used it before in the way you're using it.

Comment: Yep, that pretty much is the way for using it in combination with React Router, you can follow this issue on github for more info a and samples: https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/issues/136

Comment: Could you possibly mock up a version that uses CSSTransitionGroup. There's hardly any documentation on CSSTransition or TransitionGroup :(

Comment: Posted a solution in related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478148/page-transitions-and-component-animation-in-reactjs/45756669#45756669